# BackgroundDetect() application in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I'm learning Asterisk. In that I started to learn about BackgroundDetect() application.

There are three options are there.

BackgroundDetect(filename[|sil][|min|max]])

sil - If we specified 1000 in sil option,it'll wait 1 second after we say something to phone.

I worked sil option,it was working fine.

But I didn't understand what is the use of min and max options.

Can anyone explain me, purpose of min and max with an example?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

BackgroundDetect(filename[,sil[,min[,max[,analysistime]]]])

Plays back filename, waiting for interruption from a given digit (the digit must start the beginning of a valid extension, or it will be ignored). During the playback of the file, audio is monitored in the receive direction, and if a period of non-silence which is greater than min ms yet less than max ms is followed by silence for at least sil ms, which occurs during the first analysistime ms, then the audio playback is aborted and processing jumps to the talk extension, if available.
Parameters: 
filename: (no description)
sil:

If not specified, defaults to 1000.
min:

If not specified, defaults to 100.
max:

If not specified, defaults to infinity.
analysistime:

If not specified, defaults to infinity.